# Creating a Private Docker Registry with Authentication

Tags: docker, haproxy

So I am trying to run my own docker registry with authentication so I can access it externally. To do this I am using the docker registry image from the docker hub like so:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -d -v /opt/registry:/tmp/registry registry:0.8.1
```

I am then using HAProxy to link this to the URL `reg.mydomain.com` and add the authentication:

```
userlist auth_list
    group registry users root
    user root password [password]

backend docker-registry
    mode http
    server localhost:5000_localhost localhost:5000 cookie localhost:5000_localhost

frontend web
    mode http
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/ssl.pem
    acl domain hdr(host) -i reg.mydomain.com
    acl auth_docker_registry http_auth_group(auth_list) registry
    acl registry_ping url_sub _ping
    http-request auth realm Registry if !auth_docker_registry domain !registry_ping
    use_backend docker-registry if domain
```

Once that was running I logged in using this command:

```
root@mydomain:~# docker login https://reg.mydomain.com
Username: root
Password:
Email:
Login Succeeded
```

The problem is, when I run a command to either push or pull the the registry I get these errors:

```
root@mydomain:~# docker pull reg.mydomain.com/project1
The push refers to a repository [reg.mydomain.com/project1] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository reg.mydomain.com/project1 (1 tags)
511136ea3c5a: Pushing
2014/11/24 20:40:33 HTTP code 401, Docker will not send auth headers over HTTP.

root@mydomain:~# docker pull reg.mydomain.com/project1
Pulling repository reg.mydomain.com/project1
2014/11/24 20:40:38 Could not reach any registry endpoint
```

My guess at what the problem was is that the HTTPS connection is terminated at HAProxy and the rest of the connection (between HAProxy and Docker Registry container) is HTTP but the authentication header is still present resulting in the error on pushing. To test this I add `reqidel ^Authorization` to backend section of the HAProxy configuration to no avail.

It is also worth noting I can navigate `https://reg.mydomain.com` and sub directories such as `/v1/_ping` in a web browser and it all works as expected (I have to log in, etc.). Also, at the time of writing, I am using docker registry version `0.8.1` rather than `0.9` as the `0.9` image doesn't start.

If there is any additional information required, please let me know.

Thanks, JamesStewy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out simply telling docker to use HTTPS isn't enough, you have to force it. To do so I added `redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc } domain` to my frontend to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS which stopped the above errors from occurring.